# Set a content depending the hours or dates in php

Tags: php

Hi i want to show some content if the time is between some hour in some day and another hour in some day ¿how can i set correctly?

```
  <?php



  // de 11 am hasta 2 pm mostramos contenido del dia de hoy
  if (date('2013-8-12 12')) {

  echo "Erick Perez es seniciento de 11 am hasta 2 pm";

 } else if  (date('2013-8-12 19')) {
  echo "Erick Perez es Don Diva de 2 pm en adelante";

 }

 else {
echo "antes de que Erick Perez sea un mutante ";

 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the results of what time it is against a constant. If I understand you right, a guidance solution is this, but a full solution is not possible for me without more detail or a translation:

```
if (intval(date('H')) < 12) {
   echo "Erick doesn't start work until 12";
} elseif (intval(date('H')) > 14) {
   echo "Erick has gone home sick";
} else {
   echo "Erick is on lunch";
}
```

Comment: if is in a specific day on the year?

Comment: Wrap the whole code in a check for something like:
    if(date('Y-m-d') == '2013-07-13') { ... }
Or whatever suits your needs.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php